# Python 'if x is None' not catching NoneType

Tags: python, python-2.7

The below snippet of code keeps returning a "NoneType isn't iterable" error. Why doesn't the if statement catch this?

```
inset = set()
for x in node.contacted:
    print type(x)
    if x.is_converted() is True:
        nset.add(x)
        if x.contacted is None:
            memotable[node.gen][node.genind] = nset
        else:
            nset.union(self.legacy(x, memotable))
            memotable[node.gen][node.genind] = nset
```

Full traceback as requested:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "F:\Dropbox\CS\a4\skeleton\trialtest.py", line 142, in 
>       test_legacy_and_frac()
>
> File "F:\Dropbox\CS\a4\skeleton\trialtest.py", line 125, in
>   test_legacy_and_frac
>       cunittest2.assert_equals(set([n10,n12,n21]), t.legacy(n00,mtable))
>
> File "F:\Dropbox\CS\a4\skeleton\trial.py", line 138, in legacy
>       nset.union(self.legacy(x, memotable))
>
> File "F:\Dropbox\CS\a4\skeleton\trial.py", line 138, in legacy
>       nset.union(self.legacy(x, memotable))
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Please post the Full Traceback.. It helps understand the problem.

Comment: Are you iterating over `x.contacted` before this? Showing more code helps.

Comment: Please reduce your program to the shortest complete program that still demonstrates the error. Then copy-paste *that* program into your question. See http://SSCCE.org for more info.

Comment: We need more code to answer this usefully. Nowhere in this code do you iterate over `x`, so we're left to assume you're either iterating elsewhere, or else your error has nothing to do with the variable you're checking. If you don't provide the code needed to reproduce (or at least understand) your error, it's much harder to fix.

Comment: Added the full code and traceback

Comment: That is certainly **not** the full code. We can't tell what `memotable` holds, nor can we determine which is line 142. Please reduce your program to the smallest possible complete program that demonstrates the error and paste *that* program into your question.

Comment: Er, how much should I post then? This spans two different classes and two other test cases besides

Comment: We don't want to see the program as it sits now. Start with that program, and delete half the lines. Does the error go away? Get those lines back and delete the other half. Keep deleting lines until you have a 10-line program that demonstrates the problem. See http://SSCCE.org for information about how to accomplish that. The goal is for you to discover a **complete**, **short** program. Complete so that we can reproduce your error, Short so that we don't lose interest. (Oh, and you'll probably discover the problem on your own this way!)

Answer (score 3):

The `if` statement guarantees that `x.contacted` isn't None.

But `x.contacted` isn't what you're trying to iterate or index, so it isn't guarding anything.

There's no reason `memotable` or `memotable[node.gen]` can't be `None` even though `x.contacted` is something else. For that matter, we have no idea of what the code inside `self.legacy(x, memotable)` does—maybe it tries to iterate `x`, or `other_table[x]`, or who knows what, any of which could be `None`.

This is why you need to look at the entire traceback, not just the error string. It will tell you exactly which statement failed, and why.

---

And now that you've pasted the traceback:

```
File "F:\Dropbox\CS\a4\skeleton\trial.py", line 138, in legacy nset.union(self.legacy(x, memotable))
```

Yep, it's something that happens inside that `self.legacy` line, and it has absolutely nothing to do with `x.contacted`. The problem is almost certainly that your `self.legacy` method is returning `None`, so you're doing `nset.union(None)`.

Again, whether `x.contacted` is or is not `None` is completely irrelevant here, so your check doesn't guard you here.

If you want us to debug the problem in that function, you will have to give us the code to that function, instead of code that has nothing to do with the error. Maybe it's something silly, like doing `a + b` instead of `return a + b` at the end, or maybe it's some deep logic error, but there's really no way we can guess.

Comment: Sorry, I should've posted more code. x.contacted (which is a list), is iterated in the for statement I've added.

Comment: First, not it still isn't iterated in the `for` statement you added. Second, the traceback very clearly says that the exception is in `legacy nset.union(self.legacy(x, memotable))`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `memotable` and `memotable[node.gen]` as it can not be said to guaranteed that they are not None if `x.contacted` is not None (without the code).

If you mention the values of the variables here and Post the Full Traceback, we may be able to point out the problem more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs because the function call `self.legacy(x, memotable)` returns `None`.

The traceback indicates the error occurs in `nset.union(self.legacy(x, memotable))`, and `set.union()` raises that exception when its argument is `None`. (I'm assuming `nset` is a `set`. Your code defines `inset = set()`, but does not show where `nset` comes from)

```
>>> set().union(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```